# Ingresar varios valores Foreach

Tags: php

tengo los siguientes inputs, la idea es guardar toda esa info al tiempo, tengo entendido que hay hacer un arreglo para que funcione.

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="name_product[]">
  <input type="text" name="detail_qnty[]">
  <input type="text" name="detail_description[]">

  <input type="text" name="name_product[]">
  <input type="text" name="detail_qnty[]">
  <input type="text" name="detail_description[]">
<form>
```

aqui se ingresa los datos y con el foreach se logro que guardara 2 nombres al tiempo, pero no se como agregarle el resto de campos.

```
if (isset($_POST['detail_description'])){

        $detail_description=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,sanitize($_POST['detail_description']));
        $detail_qnty= sanitize($_POST['detail_qnty']);
        $name_product= sanitize($_POST['name_product']); 

        foreach ($_POST['name_product'] as $name_product) {
            $sql="INSERT INTO `detail_addcourier_tmp` (`id`, `id_add`, `detail_weight`, `detail_length`, `detail_width`, `detail_height`, `detail_vol`, `detail_qnty`, `detail_description`, `name_product`, `detail_created`, `level`) VALUES (NULL, '".$numbers."', '$detail_weight', '$detail_length', '$detail_width', '$detail_height', '$detail_vol', '$detail_qnty', '$detail_description', '$name_product', NOW(), '".$user->username."');";
            $insert=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        }
    }
```

intente crear un arreglo para meter todos los campos algo asi

```
$datos = array($detail_qnty => 'detail_qnty', $detail_description => 'detail_description', $name_product => 'name_product');

foreach ($datos as $data){
   aqui el insert
}
```

pero no me funciono, se guardan puros campos en blanco.

Como seria la mejor forma?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si todos los campos son array, debes manejarlos dentro del for, con sus respectivos índices.

```
if (isset($_POST['detail_description'])){
    // Necesitas un índice para recorrer todos los campos
    foreach ($_POST['name_product'] as $index => $name_product) {
        // ¿Por qué escapas solo este campo y los demás no
        $detail_description=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,sanitize($_POST['detail_description'][$index]));
        $detail_qnty= sanitize($_POST['detail_qnty'][$index]);

        // Este no requiere índice, porque estás creando la variable en el for
        $name_product= sanitize($name_product);
        // Hay otras variables que no están en tu pregunta:
        // $numbers, $detail_weight, $detail_height, etc.
        // Si también son array, deben estar dentro del for

        // No es necesario concatenar para incluir variables en una cadena
        // cuando está encerrada entre comillas dobles
        // Si se trata de elementos de objeto o array ponlos entre llaves:
        // "{$objeto->propiedad} {$array['indice']}"
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `detail_addcourier_tmp` (`id`, `id_add`, `detail_weight`, `detail_length`, `detail_width`, `detail_height`, "
            . "`detail_vol`, `detail_qnty`, `detail_description`, `name_product`, `detail_created`, `level`) VALUES "
            . "(NULL, '$numbers', '$detail_weight', '$detail_length', '$detail_width', '$detail_height', '$detail_vol', "
            . "'$detail_qnty', '$detail_description', '$name_product', NOW(), '{$user->username}');";
        $insert=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    }
}
```